# Vuejs 2 custom component validation when using v-form

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Can someone please point me to a working component example where I can trigger the validator of a custom component when I call validate on the v-form?

Inspecting the code (at runtime in the browser) of other components that come shipped with vue I see that the input components are being registered in the form as shown below in a component called 'validatable', but I cannot understand how I can do it in mine.

[image]

Registration of the inputs is hinted in the documentation too.

https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a VForm component with validation functionality like Vuetify in Vue 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410355/how-to-create-a-vform-component-with-validation-functionality-like-vuetify-in-vu)